# INSERT into MySQL table from another table

Tags: mysql, database

Working on a MySQL DB, I have a few hundred (couple thousand) rows I need to enter into a table, where part of the data is coming from a second table.

Basically the senario is:

I have a table which carries values exampled below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM table1 WHERE reference = 'ABC123';
```

returns say 3 values:
    12345
    67890
    66699

I need to insert the 3 lines from table1 into table2:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
(tbl2_unique_id, tbl1_obj_id,object_date) 
VALUES 
(XXXXXX,YYYYYY,NOW());
```

But...

XXXXXX is an incremental number (I can't make it auto_incremental) starting from '475611' (this just happens to be the last value in table2).

YYYYYY for each line is the '12345',67890','66699'

giving you

```
table2
---------------------------------
tbl2_unique_id, tbl1_obj_id, object_date
---------------------------------
475611         , 12345,  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
475612         , 67890,  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
475613         , 66699,  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Any advice?

Cheers in advance

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (tbl1_obj_id,object_date) 
select DISTINCT object_id, NOW()
FROM table1 
WHERE reference = 'ABC123'
```

You will notice that I excluded the `tbl2_unique_id` since it is auto increment, you can exclude that since you will not have a value until it is inserted.

Comment: You may want to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` depending on the time-zone settings of the server and the time-zone expected to be stored in the field.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm just adding a warning to those that might experience unexpected behavior when taking the same approach.

Comment: Cheers for that, 90% there, the only snag is that tbl12_unique_id is not auto_incremented so I will need to manually +1 that value.

Comment: It's OK I got the last bit, it's: SET @counter=475611; then (@rank:=@rank+1) in my INSERT.  Cheers guys, I have a fully working SQL now!

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
INSERT INTO orders (customer_cust_id, orderdatetime, message, taxrate, shippingprice)
SELECT '1', NOW(), null, taxrate, shippingprice FROM customer
WHERE cust_id='1';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: The `mysql>` and `->` parts of this should be stripped out.